# Error while executing msfconsole on Termux

Tags: termux

How to fix the error

> Metasploit requires the Bundler gem to be installed

While executing ./msfconsole on termux

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a pretty basic issue with MetaSploit, are you sure you want to try this on Android (instead of a full Linux distro) without any experiences?

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the error message? It supplied a command for you to follow:

```
gem install bundler
```

That should solve this issue.

Anyways, it seems like you have nearly zero experience with Metasploit Framework and Ruby - its underlying programming language. I strongly recommend **against** doing this on Android without prior experience - things *could* be more difficult to set up and deal with than when you're on a full Linux distro.

Comment: Downvoter: why?

Comment: I can't find fault with this answer. +1: score leveling for a good answer.